# Issue in updating task_struct in linux kernel scheduler

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

I want to insert a variable into struct sched_entity which is a part of task_struct in sched.h. In Linux Kernel scheduler

struct sched_entity {
..
     int my_var;
..
}

This code compiles fine but when I flashed the code into the device.

When i run it, it does not booted up. On debugging, i found that i got stuck in some core idle case. I think it is due to some strict memory barrier.

Please help me, how can i insert a variable in sched_entity or task_struct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more just a guess but try placing `int my_var` at the end of the struct instead of the middle, as I am assuming you are doing as you have ".." on both ends.

Comment: Thanks.. i have tried both at the starting and at the end. But getting the same result.

Comment: Done.. Actually i was compiling only the kernel code But after compiling the system code along with the kernel. It works